What is a proper way for organizing live streaming?
Is there an application for mobile phone that can be downloaded from the play market and would allow you to connect  to your phone as an IP camera using the connection string from , for example, the  VLC?

Why not just use VLC?

I need to get live stream from  the place of accident to site clients (blazor server), that is to use mobile phone of some person as IP camera.
